# May I lose Drive D: if I add new storage to my Azure VM?

Tags: azure, storage, azure-storage

I had a bad experience when I tried to promote my VM from a smaller size to a bigger one, in that case I lost alla data on the "Temporary Drive D:".
Now I need to add a persistent drive to my VM, would this addition result in cancelling the drive D:?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drive D should be considered volatile. Whenever you restart the server (or if the server gets restarted/moved to another instance as a result of a failover) you may lose content found on drive D. Adding a persistent drive does not require a VM restart, so adding a drive won't cause you to lose your data on D by itself.

Comment: I agree with all of this (I have done it before) and suggest user1390931 marks as correct answer. The Temporary in "Temporary Drive D:" is for real (I also was caught by this). Just to be complete, your new persistent drive is, well, persistent and wont be lost during restarts etc.